# Contact Form 7 sends message but I'm not receiving the email

Tags: wordpress, forms, email, plugins

The form on http://clinicaavivah.com.br/contato/ sends the email, but I do not receive in my mailbox. I've already tried multiple emails from different plataforms. I already installed the WP Email PLugin, configurated the smtp and the test is working fine. I even receive the emails from the plugin test. But not from Contact Form. I tried to install other form plugins but the shortcode is not rendering. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Contact Form 7 uses phpmail for sending out e-mails, whereas if you have set up an SMTP plugin, it will use an SMTP host to send the emails rather than phpmail. This is why when you test functionality it works on via sending SMTP but not Contact Form 7. See here for more information on the Contact Form 7 documentation site: [**LINK**](https://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/)

At the end of the day it may even turn out to be a hosting issue rather than a plugin issue. It might be worth contacting your host and seeing if phpmail is disabled, if it is... you might need to use another mailer plugin.